# How to declare a method parameter as any enum

Tags: java, generics, enums

I have a method on which I need to pass an enum as a parameter.

```
public <T> T doSomething(SomeEnum operation, Class<T> something);
```

I have several enums and **the method is a common one which should work with any enums**. What is the correct way to write this method signature to accept any generic enum types? I know that I can use a marker interface to this purpose, but I would like to write it with generic enum signatures. Please advise me on this.

Whats the bad idea with the below one: (It works but I get warnings from IDE saying it is a raw type. I'm not clear about the reason).

```
 public void doSomething(Enum operation);
```

Answer (score 42, accepted):

```
public <E extends Enum<E>> void doSomething(E operation);
```

**EDIT**: An example according to your modifications:

```
public class Main {

    public enum Day {
        SUNDAY, MONDAY, TUESDAY, WEDNESDAY,
        THURSDAY, FRIDAY, SATURDAY 
    }

    public <E extends Enum<E>> E doSomething(E operation, Class<E> klazz) {

        return operation;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        new Main().doSomething(Day.FRIDAY, Day.class);
    }

}
```

EDIT2:

if you need T and the Enum as separate types, then you'll need:

```
public <T, E extends Enum<E>> T doSomething(E operation, Class<T> klazz) {
```

Comment: That's the way to go. See also EnumSet for an example of this in action: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/EnumSet.html

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply, but i couldn't add this part as it again complains about signature issues. I'm sorry that i should have posted the exact signature i'm looking for. Please see my edit on the existing method signature to which i need to add what you have mentioned. In this case, how will the method signature look like???

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? or T and the enum should be separate types?

Comment: This worked perfectly for me but I don't understand why it looks like the function has two return parameters, `<E extends Enum<E>>` and `E`.

Answer (score 16):

You could do:

```
public void doSomething(final Enum<?> operation);
```

which says it needs to be an enum, but not any specific one.

Comment: To clarify: This basically just gets rid of the warning (because `Enum` and `Enum<?>` are the same thing, but one is explicit about it).

Comment: @BrendanLong: `Enum` and `Enum<?>` are not the same thing. e.g. you can add things to a `List`, but you cannot add anything to a `List<?>`

Answer (score 3):

This one is more cleared :

```
    public class EnumTest {

    protected static <E extends Enum<E>> void enumValues(Class<E> enumData) {
        for (Enum<E> enumVal: enumData.getEnumConstants()) {  
            System.out.println(enumVal.toString());
        }  
    }

    public static enum TestEnum {
        ONE, TWO, THREE;
    }

    public static void main(String param [] ) {
        EnumTest.enumValues(EnumTest.TestEnum.class);
    }
}
```

Comment: your solution does not show how one can pass an instance of the  enum e.g. call a method and pass it TestEnum.One