# Method takes as a param, enumeration values want to make it typed

Tags: scala

I have a method like:

```
def fieldsCheck(columnNames: Seq[TestProductColumnNames.Value]): ValidationNel[ColumnNameValidateError, Unit]
```

but I would like to make it typed, so it could take every

> Scala Enumeration

is it possible ?

Of course I need in this method to get values in string, or their ids. So compiler needs to know that this typed param is enum

Comment: You might try thid def * typeExample[T](tVariable : Seq[T]) : Unit = {} *

Comment: I have added more explanation coz you did not understand the question :)

Comment: in java you can do like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11435067/how-to-declare-a-method-parameter-as-any-enum . in scala I'm not sure

Comment: I don't know if I understand your question, but maybe `def fieldsCheck[T <: Enumeration](columnNames: Seq[T#Value]): ValidationNel[ColumnNameValidateError, Unit]` would work?

Comment: @KrzysztofAtłasik ah right T#Value ! :) thanks

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [@KrzysztofAtłasik](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1303324/krzysztof-at%C5%82asik) I managed to make a solution which I want to share with you:

```
trait ColumnNamesValidator[T <: Enumeration#Value] {
  val mandatoryColumnNames: Seq[T]

  def mandatoryFieldsCheck(sheetColumnNames: Seq[T]): ValidationNel[ColumnNameValidateError, Unit] = ... ( implementation )

}
```

and class using it:

```
class TestColumnNamesValidator extends ColumnNamesValidator[TestColumnNames.Value]
```